# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cognitiveservices'

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am following the tutorial from Microsoft ( https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/cognitive-services/Computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/client-library?pivots=programming-language-python ) to use cognitive service. I use herefor Visual Code and install the Azure with pip using the commandline:

```
pip install azure-cognitiveservices-vision-customvision
```

I use the first peace of code(see code below) and try to run the code. But it returns the follwowing error:

```
(myvenv) PS C:\Users\erikh\OneDrive\Documenten\Git\Python Testlab> & "c:/Users/erikh/OneDrive/Documenten/Git/Python Testlab/myvenv/Scripts/python.exe" "c:/Users/erikh/OneDrive/Documenten/Git/Python Testlab/readText.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/erikh/OneDrive/Documenten/Git/Python Testlab/readText.py", line 1, in <module>
    from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision import ComputerVisionClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cognitiveservices'
```

And here is the code which i try to execute:

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision import ComputerVisionClient
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision.models import OperationStatusCodes
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision.models import VisualFeatureTypes
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

from array import array
import os
from PIL import Image
import sys
import time

# Add your Computer Vision subscription key to your environment variables.
if 'COMPUTER_VISION_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY' in os.environ:
    subscription_key = os.environ['COMPUTER_VISION_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY']
else:
    print("\nSet the COMPUTER_VISION_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY environment variable.\n**Restart your shell or IDE for changes to take effect.**")
    sys.exit()
# Add your Computer Vision endpoint to your environment variables.
if 'COMPUTER_VISION_ENDPOINT' in os.environ:
    endpoint = os.environ['COMPUTER_VISION_ENDPOINT']
else:
    print("\nSet the COMPUTER_VISION_ENDPOINT environment variable.\n**Restart your shell or IDE for changes to take effect.**")
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, you installed the wrong package, it should be `azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision` instead of `azure-cognitiveservices-vision-customvision`.

Run the line below, then it will work fine.

```
pip install azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision
```